# Call multiple function functions periodically with different delays in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, timer, setinterval, delay

I need to call multiple functions periodically with different delays in react-native. For calling all functions periodically at once I could use -

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
     function1();
     function2();
      ....
}, 2000);
```

But in my case I need to call function1 after every 2 seconds, function2 after every 5 seconds, function3 after every 3 seconds and so on.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using multiple setIntervals in the same function and calling that function?

```
 const callIntervals = () =>{
    
  setInterval(() => {
    function1();
  }, 2000);

  setInterval(() => {
    function2();
  }, 5000);

  setInterval(() => {
    function3();
  }, 3000);
  
}
```